# How to configure mapstruct in gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, mapstruct

I tried to add mapstruct to gradle spring boot project.
here is related part of build.gradle file:

```
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0'
```

here is my interface:

```
@Mapper
public interface LogMessageMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "content", ignore = true)
    LogMessageDto toLogMessageDto(LogMessage source);

    @AfterMapping
    default void setContentString(LogMessage source, @MappingTarget LogMessageDto target) {
        target.setContent(source.getContent().toString());
    }
}
```

i received generated implementation of my mapper interface in two places:
first expected but not used by my code:
build/generated/sources/.../LogMessageMapperImpl

second unexpected but used by my code:
app/src/main/generated/.../LogMessageMapperImpl

How i have to configure gradle to make my code use properly generated classes? Thanks for any suggestions.

UPD: unexpected implementation appears only on start app from intellij idea or running tests from idea. On gradle clean build is generated only expected, desirable implementation and build is successful, tests as well.

Answer (score 1):

After removing .idea folder from project and reopen in idea problem desappeared.